# Panel with start button that moves up on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a panel with a start button in the middle of the page. When the button is clicked the panel should move up and disappear. The content of the page should start loading after the button is pressed. Something like a start button for a game.

Currently I use two html pages. The first is the panel(index.html) and the second is the content. When I press the button it moves the panel up, removes it and loads the second page. It feel a bit clunky so I wonder is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Jquery slide should work.

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kbdgmtor - On live-server looks a bit different though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kbdgmtor/3/ - Thats more like it.

Comment: The jsfjddle.net/kbdgmtor/3 one looks better although it is not exactly in the center of the page try text align center and make sure that the panel takes up the entire width and height of the screen. I'll post code later because I'm on the phone right now.

Comment: Thanks for the help! http://jsfiddle.net/kbdgmtor/4/ - Now it is center. So this is the way, after all? It should work fine with the canvas I have in game.html? Because I plan to draw and move some things in it.

Comment: I haven't worked with canvas yet myself so I can't help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for canvas. As I said in the comments I suggest doing a `text-align:center;`. This works for text and buttons. To center other elements such as `divs` try `margin: auto;`. Good luck with canvas :-)

I would also suggest expanding your css knowledge because `text-align` is very common to use as well as `margin:auto;`.

Comment: Thanks! The first attempt when It was offset I was using margin: auto. It works only in some cases. text-align didn't work either. Usually it depends of what position the element is set.